# Single phpunit.xml supporting multiple phpunit versions

Tags: phpunit

Is it possible to have in the `phpunit.xml` file sections designed for a given version (or version range) of phpunit?

For example, have one `<phpunit>` tag used when running phpunit version 9 and another `<phpunit>` tag to be used when run with phpunit10?

Example of use case:

This could be useful so that phpunit tests can be run with different versions of phpunit depending on the version installed on the system (given that one doesn't use composer to get phpunit, but uses the phpunit shipped on the system).

The only workaround I see is having a `phpunit.xml` file for phpunit9, and another one for phpunit10.

Comment: I am also not aware that you can define the configuration depending on the PHPUnit version. The phpunit.xml does not provide any functional logic but only configuration. Having a separate phpunit.xml for each PHPUnit version is the most elegant way.